# Calculate element's numeric position in a tree of elements

Tags: jquery

I'm preparing a set of presentation slides, and each slide can have a 
number of sections of code on them.  I'm making a jQuery plugin to let
me highlight individual lines of code, and move the highlight up and
down by line.

Here's an example of the markup:

```
<div class='slide'>
    <div class='section'>
        <span class='line'>Line 1</span>
        <span class='line'>Line 2</span>
    </div>
    <div class='section'>
        <span class='line'>Line 3</span>
        <span class='line'>Line 4</span>
    </div>
    <div class='section'>
        <span class='line'>Line 5</span>
        <span class='line'>Line 6</span>
    </div>
</div>


<div class='slide active'>
    <div class='section'>
        <span class='line'>Line 1</span>
        <span class='line'>Line 2</span>
    </div>
    <div class='section'>
        <span class='line'>Line 3</span>
        <span class='line selected'>Line 4</span>
        <span class='line'>Line 5</span>
    </div>
    <div class='section'>
        <span class='line'>Line 6</span>
        <span class='line'>Line 7</span>
    </div>
</div>


<div class='slide'>
    <div class='section'>
        <span class='line'>Line 1</span>
        <span class='line'>Line 2</span>
    </div>
    <div class='section'>
        <span class='line'>Line 3</span>
        <span class='line'>Line 4</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

The second slide (of three) is the active visible slide, and in that slide,
the middle line of the second code section is selected (highlighted).

I can select a line by number using jQuery like this:

```
var the_line = $(".slide.active").find("span.line")[lineno-1];
```

What I can't seem to do is calculate the line number of the currently selected line.
I tried this to compute how many lines were following the selected one, but it only
works within a single section:

```
var following_lines = $(".slide.active").find("span.line.selected").nextAll("span.line");
```

How can I get the selected line's line number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find the index of the *selected* span, you can use `index` method:

```
var $lines = $('.slide.active').find('span.line'),
    index = $lines.index( $lines.filter('.selected') ) // 3
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3dkAM/